# How to find values of a string array in a stream

Tags: java, arrays, file, java-stream

I am trying to get a solution to the following problem.

How can I find values from "conditions" in "stream"?
At the moment I can only filter with the "line.contains method". But I want that the user can give a number of conditions which would be saved in the Array "conditions". I tried to build a for-loop in the stream.filter but I failed.^^ Maybe you know an efficient way. :)

Thanks.

```
private static void streamSelectedFile(String p, String[] conditions) {
    try (
        Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(p), StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)) {       
        Stream<String> filteredStream = 
                stream.filter(line -> line.contains("conditionValue"));     
        filteredStream.forEach(elem -> {
            System.out.println(elem + " Path: " + p);
        });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: `stream.filter(line -> Stream.of(conditions).allMatch(line::contains))` ?

Comment: Thats it!! Thank you very much. I lost many hours for this problem and the solution looks so simple... -.- :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `allMatch`

```
stream.filter(line -> Stream.of(conditions).allMatch(line::contains))
```